# Django library/app for "On site Recurring Payment" integration using eWay Payment gateway

Tags: django, payment-gateway, recurring-billing

I am trying to integrate "On site Recurring Payment" using [eWay Payment Gateway](http://www.eway.com.au/), in my website and Since I am using Django as a development framework so I was looking for an existing library/app in Django which helps me, with that.

For which [Django-Merchant](https://github.com/agiliq/merchant) seems to be very promising. But while going through their [API Doc](https://django-merchant.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) I realized that Django-Merchant does NOT facilitates "[Recurring Payments](http://www.eway.com.au/developers/api/recurring)" in On-site Processing.

Is there any other library for eWay Payment Gateway in Django that I can use to achieve "On site Recurring Payments"? or any other way out in Django-Merchant.

Example:
The recurring functionality is available for braintree integration:

```
>>> resp = braintree.recurring(10, credit_card, options = options)
```

I am looking for the same thing in eWay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have contributed to [Django-Merchant](http://merchant.agiliq.com/) for above mentioned features. As, It supports many payment gateways and is most popular in the Django community for payment gateway Integration.

Refer latest version of Django-Merchant for changes. you can find them [here](https://github.com/agiliq/merchant).